# What does D3 do that Angular cannot?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I'm much n00b with D3.js.

I'm using it in an Angular project but I'm considering to get rid of it. Maybe I missed something.

My understanding is that the strength of D3 comes from being able to update the DOM along some data. Here's typically how I would use it:

```
// JS Data
[{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Red',
  is_warm: true
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Blue',
  is_warm: false
}]

// With the following code:
colors = d3.select($element.find('ul')[0]).selectAll('li.color').data(colorArray, function(d){ return d.id }).enter();
colors.text(function(d) { return d.name }).classed('color', true).classed('warm', function(d) { return d.is_warm; });

<!-- Generates -->
<ul>
  <li class="color warm">Red</li>
  <li class="color">Red</li>
</ul>
```

But I could definitely do the same with AngularJs:

```
$scope.colors =     [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Red',
  is_warm: true
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Blue',
  is_warm: false
}]

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="color in colors" class="color" ng-class="color.is_warm ? 'warm' : ''"></li>
</ul>
```

Which would generate more or less the same code.

So what's the point of using D3 here, on top of AngularJs?

From my understanding, the main difference is **when** the redraw occurs:

- With D3, it should be manually called (Eg. when the data has been updated by the server)
- With AngularJs, it will be during `$digest` cycle, which can be slow if the client has little CPU.

Am I right? Is that the only difference? Ain't it possible to set the AngularJs redraw frequency manually? Why using D3 with AngularJs then?

Thanks

Comment: d3 clearly uses a jQuery paradigm. It's simply a non-sense to use it with AngularJS, besides maybe a short transition period.

Comment: d3, Angular, jQuery, whatever... they are all extensions of JavaScript, so there's **nothing** that one can do and that others can't. It's just the question of how much effort you need to put into it.

Comment: Well if I go to the site of D3 it says right in the sales pitch "D3’s emphasis on web standards gives you the full capabilities of modern browsers without tying yourself to a proprietary framework" - that translates to me like "Use D3 if you don't like large frameworks such as AngularJS"

Comment: Angular and jQuery can well co-exists, It is clearly said here as **Yes** https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq#does-angular-use-the-jquery-library- **angular.element** will act as **$**

Comment: @ZigmaEmpire though if you ever find yourself using it you're probably doing this in a 'non-Angular' way. I've nothing but headaches with *raw* jQuery and angular. AugustinRiedinger You cannot compare D3 with Angular. D3 is a data presentation library. Angular is a web application framework. You can use [angular with d3](https://www.dashingd3js.com/d3-resources/d3-and-angular) if you wish, but they are not replacements for each other. If you're using d3 to perform DOM manipulations outside SVG graphs you *might* be doing it wrong

Comment: Also, @Gimby, Angular isn't a proprietary framework; it's open source.

Comment: @DanPantry I presume using **angular.element** is a proper angular coding only and angular never said that we should not use jQuery, Actually angular uses jQuery inside it, you can click on function names for angular.element it will go to jquery site only

Comment: I feel like this question is not going to be producing useful answers nor comments. What can D3 do that Angular can't is like asking: what can a washing machine do that a lawn mower can't? The fact is they are both machines built for a purpose. The same for D3 and Angular, 2 frameworks built for a particular purpose. D3 for data visualisations, Angular for single-page web applications. This discussion can go on and on and never really produce something useful. And that would beat the purpose of stackoverflow.

Comment: @ZigmaEmpire no it doesnt it uses jqlite, which is different.

Comment: Ok, I giveup, better you refer the docs

Comment: @ZigmaEmpire angular will use jquery *if* jquery is loaded before angular, however angular itself uses jqlite and it is recommended you stick with jqlite. Angular itself does *not* use jQuery by default, only a subset of its functionality. Quoted from the [docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/docs/api/ng/function/angular.element). There is no need to use jQuery with Angular.

Answer (score 1):

To actually answer the question:

You cannot compare Angular and D3 in this manner. Angular is an application framework, whereas D3 is a data presentation framework. The fact that D3 can manipulate the DOM is purely because it needs some way of manipulating the DOM to display data.

Angular, on the other hand, is a framework for MVC applications and is not just limited to displaying data but is much more generalised than D3.

Them both being libraries is where the similarities end; they are intended for different purposes and do different jobs. D3 materializes data (and one of those ways is through the DOM), where-as Angular creates rich web applications.